# EE 2.8.1 & CartThrob 2.5: multi_add_to_cart_form not working

Tags: cartthrob

Is anyone running EE 2.8.1 and Cartthrob 2.5 getting the multi_add_to_cart_form to work?  It seems to not be posting the values into the cart.  I have gotten the one item add_to_cart_form to work and can see cart entries perfectly when using that tag, but the multi_add_to_cart shows nothing when attempting to view the cart.  Here is my barebones hardcoded attempt template code:

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form return="shopping_cart"}
     <input type="hidden" name="entry_id[1]" value="105" />
     <input type="hidden" name="entry_id[2]" value="103" />
     <input type="hidden" name="entry_id[3]" value="101" />
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
{/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
```

I've also tried using the multi_add_to_cart_form nested in a {exp:channel:entries} tag pair, but it also does not seem to be posting the entries into the cart:

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form return="shopping_cart"}
     {exp:channel:entries channel="products" status="Open"}
          <input type="hidden" name="entry_id[{count}]" value="{entry_id}">
     {/exp:channel:entries}
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
{/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
```

I'd very much appreciate if anyone with CT 2.5 and EE 2.8.1 could confirm if they can get the multi_add_to_cart tag working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got a scheduled callback from CartThrob support and it was a simple 5-minute fix.  It turns out that the quantity field for each entry_id is required when using the {exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form} tag pair.  In the single {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form} tag no quantity field is necessary, and adding to cart that way defaults the quantity to 1.

So the following code now sends the correct information to the cart:

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form return="shopping_cart"}
     {exp:channel:entries channel="products" status="Open"}
          <input type="hidden" name="entry_id[{count}]" value="{entry_id}">
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity[{count}]" value="{entry_id}">
     {/exp:channel:entries}
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
{/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
```